# How do functions work?

Tags: python, function

Except for in maths examples, of which there are many, I don't understand functions properly. 
What is wrong with this?

```
def get_address():
    address = raw_input ("What is your address: ")
    return address
```

I'm not able to get a variable `address` returned for use later.

Comment: because you're not assigning the return of `get_address` maybe?

Comment: `result = get_address()`. Now `result` is equal to whatever this function returns.

Comment: Returning `address` doesn't create a `address` variable in the scope where you called the function from. You need to assign the return. Show how you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did, you failed to call the function that is why you facing this problem.

Use this instead and you can able to get the address of a function.

**In Python v2.x**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def get_address():
        address = raw_input("What is your address: ")   
        return address

a = get_address()
print a
```

**What is raw_input?**

It ask the user (the optional arg of raw_input([arg])), gets input from the user and returns the data input by the user in a string.

**In Python v3.x:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
name=input('Enter your name : ')
print ("Welcome %s, Let us be friends!" % name);
```

Comment: You want to use `input` rather than `raw_input` in Python 3.

Comment: well, I corrected it,its editing mistake. Obviously its input. :)

Comment: Im trying to compact my code with functions, if I wanted  generic question that may be more suitable for a function I suppose